# Unexplained FirebaseError "Failed Precondition"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm getting this error when running in production. This doesn't happen when I run locally against the emulators.

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.9.4): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}

I believe I have an index covers the query I'm trying to make. And I've tested my security rules and it should be allowed. In both those cases, I'd expect the errors to be more descriptive anyway.

Where do I find more information about this error so I can debug?

The code causing the error is:

```
let args = [
  collection(`room/${roomId}/messages`), 
  where(['type', '==', 'ALERT']),
  orderBy('date', 'desc'),
  limit(100)
];
let ref = query(args);
onSnapshot(ref, snap => {
  let value = snap.docs.map(doc => ({
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id,
  }));
  emit(value);
});
```

And this, I think, is the relevant index:

```
{
  "collectionGroup": "messages",
  "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldPath": "room",
      "order": "ASCENDING"
    },
    {
      "fieldPath": "type",
      "order": "ASCENDING"
    },
    {
      "fieldPath": "date",
      "order": "DESCENDING"
    }
  ]
},
```

And the relevant security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: 
        if false;
    }

    match /rooms/{roomId} {

      match /messages/{messageId} {
        allow read, write: 
          if roomId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.rooms;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'd like to share the code that generates the error, as well as the index?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added the offending code above. Like I said, though, it runs perfectly and give me a result when I run it in the simulator, which makes me think the code is fine. It's only giving me this error when I run it in production.

Comment: Your index is for a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), but your query is not that. It is just a normal query targeting a subcolleciton.  The code and index are not related to each other.  Your rule will also not work the way you expect because the query does not match the requirements of the rule.

Comment: Consider that this could just a problem with the emulator.  It does not run all the same code as production.  Production is considered canonical, the emulator can only strive to be like that.  You can file a bug report with exact repro steps in its [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues).

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. The index does have a "queryScope" of "collection". But you were right, adding another rule without the "room" fieldPath did the trick and it seems to be working now. I'm not sure what you mean by the query not matching the requirements of the rule. Can you explain, or point me at the docs that do? Thanks.

Comment: On another note, it used to be the case that if a query needed an index, you'd get a direct link to create the index in the browser console. Has that been removed?